# Increasing count when random value changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to add 1 to the count every time a value between 1 and 10 occurs.

So for example, when the random number is a 2, I want to add 1 to the count for 2. When the next random number is generated, let's say it's a 5, the count for 2 remains as it is and 1 is added to the count for 5 and so on.

The random number is generated in a cell on Sheet 1.

The table displayed below is on Sheet 2. I am using an IF statement in the **Result Yes?** column to return a 1 when the random number corresponds.

I understand this may require a VBA solution.

Any help would be great!

Count table

[image]

Comment: How and when do you generate the random number?

Comment: It's just a regular random number generated in excel using RAND

Comment: You mean it's like rolling a dice and tracking the results?

Comment: Yes, that's about it

Comment: But I dont want to create a list of 1000 "rolls" and accumulate the totals. I want the count to add as the new random number is generated

Comment: where is the number created - ist there a cell with a RAND-function and you hit F9 every time????

Comment: random number is created on sheet 1

Comment: the table is on sheet 2

Comment: random number created in B3 on sheet 1. Then I just use simple IF statement on sheet 2 for the corresponding number

Comment: so IF random number is 2, then yes for Result Ye? 2

Comment: I suggest that you update your question to make the whole scenario clearer ...

Comment: Keep in mind `RAND()` changes value every time there is a recalculation, so IMO excel-formulas are a no-go

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will update the question.

Comment: Sorry, but it still is not clear how and when the random number gets updated. Without knowing that it is not possible to suggest a solution.

Comment: Ah Sorry Ike. The random number is updated whenever any cell on any sheet is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres my best guess at what you are trying to acheive.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourWorksheetsName")
    
    Randomize
    Dim rndVal As Integer: rndVal = Int((11 * Rnd))
    
    ws.Cells(2, 6).Value = rndVal
    
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(12, 2)).ClearContents
    ws.Cells(rndVal + 2, 2).Value = "Yes"

    ws.Cells(rndVal + 2, 3).Value = ws.Cells(rndVal + 2, 3).Value + 1

End Sub
```

With this implementation you will need to add the code to the worksheet which will trigger the random value to update. (I read your comment and saw what you actually wanted to do).
[image]
Good luck